# Presenting a new window/view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

```
import UIKit

class StartUp: UIViewController {

var window: UIWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var window2: UIWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var window3: UIWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var window4: UIWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
var startController: UIViewController?
var startController2: UIViewController?
var startController3: UIViewController?
var startController4: UIViewController?
var newViewController = false

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    //Get current app config (position codes and check if app is active)

    if (checkInternetConnection() == true) {

        PFConfig.getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (parseConfig: PFConfig?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            //Determine where to start app

            //Already logged in
            if (currentUser != nil) {

                self.startController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as TabBar

            }

            //Not logged in
            else {

                self.startController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginStart") as UINavigationController

            }

            self.window.rootViewController = self.startController

            self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()

            //If the app is disabled, display the inactive/disabled/error screnen.
            if (parseConfig?["active"] as Bool? == false) {

                self.startController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("block") as AppBlock

                self.window2.rootViewController = self.startController

                self.window2.makeKeyAndVisible()
            }
        }
    }

    else {

        //Already logged in
        if (currentUser != nil) {

            self.startController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBar") as TabBar

        }

            //Not logged in
        else {

            self.startController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginStart") as UINavigationController

        }

        self.window3.rootViewController = self.startController

        self.window3.makeKeyAndVisible()

        self.startController = self.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("block") as AppBlock

        self.window4.rootViewController = self.startController

        self.window4.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
}
```

I have what I think is a weird situation. If the first if statement ,`checkInternetConnection()`, is true, I go on to continue figuring out what window/view to present. Everything here works perfectly. However, in the `else` part, no windows/views are presented. I can't figure out why this is happening....it's really weird that it works in one section but not the other....

Any ideas?

Also in some cases two windows/views are created. Would this be a problem? I don't think so since if the `parseConfig` is false, the two windows are created and displayed correctly.

Comment: The last 5 lines of your code look very strange, what are you trying to do? you load startController with  TabBar or loginStart, than you assigned it to window3,than you load start Controller block and assigned it again to window4? Very confusing!

Comment: I know I'm probably doing it some weird way but what I'm doing is creating both views. In theory, window 4 will be on top of window 3. When I lower the alpha of window 4, window 3 should appear. However, the windows aren't even being created!

Comment: I would use UIViews instead UIWindow (unless you have a good reason for it) What I would do would be create all the views add using add to subView so you can easily show, hide, fade, etc

Comment: Do you mean by creating xib's of the views?

Comment: No just create like this var view: UIView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

Comment: You welcome, let me know later how it go or if you need any tips (that I may can help with) Good Luck!